# Surjective linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have some trouble with solving this problem:

Let $V$, $W$ be two vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively. Let $T, S: V \rightarrow W $ be linear transformations with $T$ being surjective. Show that $T+tS$ is surjective for all $t \in \mathbb{C} $ except a finite number of values.

The only thing I get from this is that $m $ must be greater than $n$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: let $v_1,\ldots v_m$ be a basis of $V$. $T(v_1)\ldots T(v_m)$ spans $W$. When does $T+tS$ applied to each of the basis vectors not span $W$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is surjective, there exists $e_1,..,e_n\in V$ such that $T(e_1),...,T(e_n)$ is a basis of $W$, let $U=Vect(e_1,..,e_n)$ and $(f_1,..,f_n)$ a basis of $W$, consider $M_U$ the matrix of $T$ relatively to $(e_1,..,e_n)$ and $(f_1,..,f_n)$ consider $P(t)=det(M_U+tN_U)$ where $N_U$ is the matrix of the restriction of $S$ to $U$ relatively to $(e_1,..,e_n)$ and $(f_1,..,f_n)$ it is a non trivial polynomial since $P(0)\neq 0$ an it has a finite number of roots.